# Minimum memory required for SUB operation using accumulator?

Tags: memory, accumulator

This question might not be best questioned here but here it goes.

So, would the minimum memory addresses required for a sub operation in a cpu using an accumulator be 1 or 2?

I would say 1, since you can subtract the same value and store it in the same address, but when I asked a friend, he told me that "you assume 2 values not 1. So you begin with 2 memory addresses.". Is that really a requirement, theoretically speaking? (Practically, I don' see why would I not be able to use only 1 memory address).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have not specified an architecture, an operation on values in registers is possible, and may or may not meet your *applicable* definition of "memory".  But what about storage of the program opcode(s)?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry, I forgot to define that. I meant in an architecture where the program and values are all stored in the memory (like a von Neumann). I was only actually asking about the value addresses needed.
Taking opCodes too, the answer would be 4(load, sub, store, value1)?

Comment: Not necessarily, no.  Also you neglect to specify operand sizes in terms of addressable units - ie, if you have 32 bit operands on a byte addressable 32 bit machine.